# __latexindent_temp.tex VSCode Error

Tags: errors, compiling, compilation-error, latexindent

The Latex Workshop VSCode Extension has been generating a file called `__latexindent_temp.ex` every build.

[image: Annoying Error]

Contrary to this message, I have ensured that MiKTeX is fully updated. I have tried reinstalling MikTex, changing the Latex Workshop Extension "recipe", and reinstalling the extension.

I'm debating where I should simply ignore the extra file and error altogether:

[image]

Ideally, a person wiser than me has a solution!

Comment: Did you by chance use the vim plugin and try to do `==`?

Comment: No, I did not use the vim plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After hours of hair ripping, I began down the rabbit hole of my Perl installation. I decided to uninstall Active Perl and replaced it with Strawberry Perl. This did not fix the original error, but it threw a useful one!
[image]

I discovered that this perl module was not included by default on my machine. If you had my original error or this new one, make sure you are using *Strawberry* Perl and run:

`cpan install Log::Log4perl`

**UPDATE (2022)**

According to library's author, `Log4perl` is no longer required in the latest installation of `latexindent`. Therefore, **make sure you are using the latest version of the library to avoid this error.**

Comment: Log4Perl no longer required :)

Comment: Excellent news - thank you!

Comment: Did you find out how to get rid of the `__latexindent_temp.tex` files too?

Comment: With the new Perl installation, the temp file disappeared.