# What is the file __latexindent_temp.tex?

Tags: vscode

I'm using Visual Studio Code with the LaTeX Workshop extension. It works fine, but sometimes a file named `__latexindent_temp.tex` is automatically generated.

It keeps working fine if I delete it and it is not recreated after that.

I found very few information on the web and only two related post on this StackExchange ([here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/581846/latexindent-temp-tex-vscode-error) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/520978/adding-entry-bib-file-breaks-latex-workshop-in-vs-code)) that are related to bugs.

What is the purpose of this file? Is it safe to put it on my `.gitignore` file?

Comment: I can't answer about its purpose but it's definitely safe to put in `.gitignore` as it's something generated by the editor and does not have any significance to LaTeX itself.

Comment: My guess is that it's some internal thing that the user should normally not care about anyway, but if the editor dies before it has the chance to delete the file then the file remains for the user to see... (by the way there's also `.git/info/exclude`)

Answer (score 1):

A bit more digging and this is a file created by VSCode if you have formatOnSave set in VSCode. It's a working file and not surprisingly (given the name) not of any relevance. It should be deleted by VSCode normally, so there might be some oddity in your VSCode setup, but I can't elucidate more than that.

Comment: I have the key `"latex-workshop.latex.autoBuild.cleanAndRetry.enabled": false` in my workspace settings, maybe this is linked.